# Is it possible to have a constant rotating DIV or image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have an image or DIV to start rotating on click similar to a record player. Is it possible to have it smooth and with javascript?

Thankyou very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the rotation in CSS3.

```
@keyframes rotate
{
     0%   { transform: rotate(0); }
     25%  { transform: rotate(90); }
     50%  { transform: rotate(180); }
     75%  { transform: rotate(270); }
     100% { transform: rotate(360); }
}

#rotating_div
{
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function rotate(id) {
    div = getElementById['id'];
    div.style.animation-play-state = running;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="rotating_div" onclick="rotate("rotating_div")"></div>
```

Use the prefix -moz- and -webkit- to get the CSS3 to work in FF and other browsers. Have a look here: [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp)

Good luck! :)

Comment: Wow thanks! How could I do something where it eases in but instead of just running the time specified, it will just keep rotating. So something like this: animation-timing-function:ease-in-linear; but obviously that doesn't work, haha.

Comment: animation-iteration-count tells how many times it should repeat. (You could use infinite)

Comment: @keyframes rotate
{
     0%   { transform: rotate(0); }
     25%  { transform: rotate(50); }
     50%  { transform: rotate(120); }
     75%  { transform: rotate(250); }
     100% { transform: rotate(360); }
}
 IF you do this, then it will fade all the time

Comment: I actually am using infinite, it's just that I want it to ease in on click and then loop infinitely. I have this:     animation-name:             ring; 
    animation-duration:         10s; 
    animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
    animation-timing-function:linear;

Comment: But if you say that the iteration is 1, and in javascript you specify that after 4 seconds it should change the animation-name to "rotate-without-ease"

Comment: Oh use ease-in on one animation. Then you use linear on another. Then you use JavaScript to change from the ease-in animation to the other animation after 10 seconds.

Comment: Oh... so   from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to { 
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  } will make the animation just stop and then loop for the specified time?

Comment: just use div.style.animation-name = "name";

Comment: I mean this: Animation 1: Eases in, plays ONE time. Animation 2: Linear, plays for ever. Use JavaScript to change the animation from Animation 1 to Animation 2 after 10 seconds. Because that's the time it takes for Animation 1 to complete.

Comment: Oh ok! That's easy enough. Thankyou so much! The other answers pale in comparison. Thanks for the help!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Search this on google

> Do a barrel roll

should give you an idea :)

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Do+a+barrel+roll

Comment: Cute (in the "Stop it and give me my search result" sense) though that is in supporting browsers, it doesn't help implement the effect at all.

Comment: Thankyou! But how would I keep it in constant motion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `window.setInterval` to control an animation.  More info [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/)

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to go for a combination of JS Timers, and CSS3 Transitions, but looking at w3schools.com, I saw there actually was animation support in CSS3.

I think this would be implented as following;

```css
@keyframes rotate
{
     0%   { transform: rotate(0); }
     25%  { transform: rotate(90); }
     50%  { transform: rotate(180); }
     75%  { transform: rotate(270); }
     100% { transform: rotate(360); }
}

div #lp
{
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```

This isn't really a JS solution, but this is by far the simplest solution, but if your target browser isn't supporting CSS3, then you might want to use an  animated GIF image.

You will have to make it work in the other webbrowsers too, but it's just to add the -webkit- tags and such, more information on the subject is found here: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp and here: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

(Sorry to those who don't like w3schools.com)

Comment: Thankyouuu! Very informative and very detailed. Thankyou so much for taking the time to put this together. I would do a GIF but the images are created dynamically so... This will work perfectly though! CSS3 really makes everything a whole lot easier (and a whole lot funner!) Your the best!